# Is there any way to test the unreleased build on itunesconnection after Apple certified?

Tags: iphone, ios, distribution, app-store-connect

Is there any way to test the unreleased build on itunesconnect after Apple certified?

Following article shows how to get the unreleased app but just works on the very first version
"Is it possible to get App Link for App which is not approved yet? (http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/10044)"

But my issue is there's already some old version on the Apple Store, and I just submitted a new version, this version was passed by Apple certificate but not released yet.
As the concern is after I release it, any issue happened on this build was not revertible.(After Apple certificate and encryption, sometimes the app will perform not exactly like what your debugging build, I just suffered a lot from this issue, that's why I want to check the real final build)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think there is a way to do this by redeeming the app with a promo code. Apple allows this so you can send it to testers and app reviewers before you release.

Comment: note: im not sure that you can do this for an update. Your promo codes still work , but only for the live version and not the binary that is ready for release.

Comment: Is there a way to test for an update other than the promo code method?